# Excel - How to lookup multiple values in comma separated range

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I have this comma separated values in column A in and corresponding values in column B.

I want to lookup values of column E and return the values in column F where duplicate values return the next corresponding value of the same match.

[image: excel lookup]

I have tried this formulae but did not get the desired results

```
    =INDEX($B$2:$B$13, SMALL(IF("*"&E2&"*"=$A$2:$A$13, 
ROW($A$2:$A$16116)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$13))+1, 0), 
COUNTIF(E2:$E$2, E2)))
```

Please anyone here to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for, there may be a much more elegant & eloquent way to solve however even this works as well,

Formula used in cell **E2**

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,
(ROW($B$2:$B$13)-1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&D2&", ",", "&$A$2:$A$13&", ")),
COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2))),"")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Answer (score 0):

In F2:

`=INDEX(FILTER(B$2:B$13,ISNUMBER(FIND(","&E2&",",","&SUBSTITUTE(A$2:A$13," ","")&","))),COUNTIF(E$2:E2,E2))`

and copied down.